# core.excludesfile and user.excludesfile in git

Tags: git

What is the difference between `core.excludesfile` and `user.excludesfile` in git repository?

I am using following code to exclude some of my configuration files but did not exlude my configuration file.

```
$ echo 'globals/js/config.js' > .gitignore_local
$ git add .gitignore_local
$ git config user.excludesfile .gitignore_local
```

When I pull files from my local folder using

```
$ git pull [remote_path_alias] master
```

But `config.js` file update.

Answer (score 1):

`core.excludesfile` is recognized by Git. `user.excludesfile` is not a valid git configuration setting.

To set a configuration variable for a user you use (the slightly unfortunately named) `--global` with `git config`.